# Callback Detectors: Connection to High Confidence C&C Server IP Detected

Tags: siem

We are in the process of tuning McAfee ESM. Below is the log-

Source IP = 173.224.123.242 
Destination IP = Internal IP (always the same)

Source Port = 443
Destination Port = 3740 (2502, 2442, 1208, 1118, 3526, 1175, 4499,4466)

alert 2

Source User = NA, 
Destination User = NA

First Event - 05/13/2016 19:50:09
Last Event - 05/13/2016 19:50:09
Event Count - 2

Message - Callback Detectors: Connection to High Confidence C&C Server IP Detected
Application - 
Average Severity = 90
Signature ID = 305-284

Kindly help me understand why  am I getting these and what action should I take?

Answer (score 1):

The IPS sensor seems to believe that 173.224.123.242 is a C&C server (this information is taken from McAfee itself, which analyzes the server to determine if it is malicious or not).

A C&C would be a server that has been compromised and manages a botnet, for example. This is not a good sign.

If this signature is showing up always for the same internal host, disconnect it from the network immediately and determine if it has been compromised or not (run an up to date AV, check the processes that are active, etc.). If the external IP belongs to your company, this may indicate a false-positive. Then, make sure the server is really OK and create a filter to ignore this alert in the future.

Hope it helps! :)